# Display label in windows 10 taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I want to display label like DU meter [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8cnJ.png) in windows 10 taskbar using C#.
I googled many times but didn't get any helpful resource. If anybody can help me in any form to solve this problem it'll be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *You* might want this, but I can guarantee that none of your *users* want this. So many arrogant programmers did this that Microsoft had to start hiding notification area icons by default. Don't ruin our ability to have nice things.

Comment: @CodyGray why does it make a programmer arrogant to want to include such a feature? Especially if they know that the clients are able to disable this feature if they want to?